# How to fire an event on file when file modification has stopped in Java using WatchService?

Tags: java, polling, watchservice

I have been using WatchService api to implement this. I want to check whether a file is unchanged for 10 seconds and if it is so, then process the file. I have developed a code which checks whether file has been modified or not i a directory but cannot determine the last modification time. Kindly edit my code or suggest any other answer.

```
public class Poller {
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException,
        IOException, InterruptedException {
    Date oldDate;
    Path tmpPath = Paths.get("E:/Demo/DEC");
    WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

    // Watching the /tmp/nio/ directory
    // for MODIFY and DELETE operations
    tmpPath.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
            StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);

    /*
     * Keep polling for events on the watched directory,
     */
    for (;;) {
        WatchKey key = watchService.take();

        // Poll all the events queued for the key
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
            switch (kind.name()) {
            case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                Path filename = (Path) event.context();
                System.out.println("Modified: " + event.context());
                break;
            case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                System.out.println("Delete: " + event.context());
                break;
            }
        }
        // reset is invoked to put the key back to ready state
        boolean valid = key.reset();

        // If the key is invalid, just exit.
        if (!valid) {
            break;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Suppose i have file called input.csv in the specified folder and while the code is running, I modify input.csv, then the WatchService API recieves that event.

Comment: Don't you want to know when you have't got ENTRY_MODIFY events for 10 seconds.  How do you want to use the modification date?

Comment: I just want to get the time difference between last modification time and current time. If it is 10 seconds that means the file hasnt been modified for the last 10 secs. The only i can process the file.